# Need a LostFocus event for WinForms UserControl hosted in MS Office VBA through COM Interop

Tags: winforms, user-controls, activex, com-interop, lostfocus

We implemented an ActiveX control based on WinForms UserControl in VB.NET 2010. It is used on VBA UserForms through COM Interop. All works ok - except one thing. When the input focus is moved from the ActiveX to another VBA native control on the UserForm (like say Command Button), we cannot detect this thing. Such standard WinForms control events like Leave or Validating aren't triggered in this case.

How to track it (better using a "managed" way, without WinAPI tricks)?

Note that our UserControl contains other WinForms controls like buttons or textboxes, so we need a LostFocus event for the whole control exposed as an ActiveX regardless of what constituent part was selected.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get this fixed with managed API. If you're OK with P/invoke, [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/`WH_CBT`/`HCBT_SETFOCUS` would be the way to go.

There's probably another quirk you may be experiencing. Try to put a text cursor (caret) into any of the editable fields inside your managed control, then switch away to another app with Alt-Tab. Then go back to your app with Alt-Tab. Is the cursor still in place or has it disappeared? In the latter case, you're after `HCBT_ACTIVATE`.

The .NET Framework implementation of ActiveX Control COM interfaces for `UserControl` expects some protocol calls from the ActiveX host. E.g., it expects `IOleInPlaceObject::UIDeactivate` to be called when the focus moves to another location outside `UserControl`, or `IOleInPlaceActiveObject::OnFrameWindowActivate method` to be called with the host's frame window becomes inactive, because user has switched to another app. You can study [the Framework source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx) for more details.

Unfortunately, not all ActiveX containers follow this protocol closely; apparently, VBA doesn't. An ultimate solution is to implement an intermediate layer (preferably, in C++/ATL) which would serve as ActiveX control to the VBA host and as ActiveX container to the managed .NET control, fixing all those quirks in between. It's do-able, but quite tedious.